# How can I start a nsca server on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, nagios3

On Ubuntu 14.04 after installing nsca package, I cannot start the service because of this error (retrieved from syslog):

```
nagios nsca[621]: Cannot write to pidfile '/var/run/nsca.pid' - check your privileges.
```

Answer (score 1):

**It is not an elegant solution from the system point of view. But it is a simple, secure, fast method. It uses upstart config, instead of "deprecated" init.d script.**

Since Ubuntu 14.04 you must override default startup settings for nsca daemon. This is because the `/etc/init.d/nsca` script cannot create a pid file in `/run`. Since 14.04 release this directory is writable only by root. Therefore we can create a separate init config file for starting up nsca server.

Create an init startup script, in `/etc/init/nsca.conf`:

```
#!upstart
description "NSCA Nagios Server"

env DAEMON=/usr/sbin/nsca
env USER=nagios
env PIDFILE=/var/run/nsca.pid
env CONF=/etc/nsca.cfg

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown

respawn
expect fork

# log by default - syslog
exec start-stop-daemon --start --exec $DAEMON --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid $USER -- -c $CONF
```

Remove links for starting up:

```
update-rc.d -f nsca remove
```

Remove old startup script.

```
rm /etc/init.d/nsca
```

Create symlink for working autocomplete:

```
ln -s /lib/init/upstart-job /etc/init.d/nsca
```

Reload init:

```
sudo initctl reload-configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove

```
--make-pidfile
```

from Vladimir's answer to get this running properly as the nsca server itself already creates a pid file. Also make sure that you have the same values in

```
/etc/nsca.cfg
```

What helped a lot is to enable logging of the nagios server. I used this  [guide](http://www.charlesjudith.com/2014/03/11/create-a-log-file-for-nsca/) to enable it.

Comment: Did you mean it as a comment to the answer or a separate answer?